# Problems with WebView in Flutter

Tags: function, flutter, dart, plugins, webview

Heyy.. Am trying to use a webview in my flutter app but all its does is return a blank white page..

This is my code:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';


class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}


class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

 Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
       backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        body:
           WebView(
                  initialUrl: 'https://www.instagram.com/p/B_dvb9mAbxR/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link',
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller.complete(webViewController);
                  },

                  ),

   );

  }
}
```

Please I need show help

Comment: Where you are running the code...virtual device or real phone?

Comment: on a phone and I have edited my question

Comment: In my phone your code runs fine. In the virtual device did not work. Any traces?

I put below the traces I get in AVD:


E/flutter ( 9851): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(error, Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@eaae9c8 -- the specified display can not be found, null)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33679763/chrome-inspector-shows-android-webview-in-avd-but-not-on-actual-device

Comment: is that link an answer?

Comment: please can i see a picture of how it works on your phone

Comment: this is the error am getting..                                                                                                                 I/BufferQueueProducer(21222): [SurfaceTexture-0-21222-5](this:0x8a0f2000,id:5,api:1,p:414,c:21222) queueBuffer: slot 0 is dropped, handle=0xa471be20

Comment: I dont know how add an image in the comments. 

I hope the link I shared with you help. Its a similar problem.

Comment: well i dont understand how to use the link.. Can you just use the answer question method and then type the code from the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is an old implementation. [Here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-webview#9) is a working sample on both Android and iOS using the current implementation of the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) plugin:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: WebViewApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class WebViewApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebViewApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebViewApp> createState() => _WebViewAppState();
}

class _WebViewAppState extends State<WebViewApp> {
  late final WebViewController controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = WebViewController()
      ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
      ..loadRequest(
        Uri.parse('https://www.instagram.com'),
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter WebView'),
      ),
      body: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Android output:

[image]

iOS output:

[image]